# Вывод конкретной строки из таблицы C# MS SQL

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server, datagridview

Всем привет, мне нужно вывести в DataGridView из таблицы БД MS SQL определённый набор строчек, которые записаны в файле. С выводом из файла я сам, подскажите как вывести конкретную строчку ?

---

Пример: Есть таблица dbo.test из неё нужно загрузить в DataGridView, 1 и 5 строчку остальные не трогать.

Comment: Может быть вы под "строчкой" подразумеваете строки с id = 1 и id = 5 (где id - первичный ключ таблицы)? И как раз файл содержит на каждой строке номера?

Comment: Да, это и имею ввиду.

Comment: тогда вам нужно использовать конструкцию `WHERE id IN (1,5,17)` и понимать, что конструкция `IN` очень неэффективна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В базе данных нет такого "1 и 5 строка". Строки хранятся сортированные по cluster index (если он конечно есть), который в норме соответствует первичному ключу. Если при выборке вы хотите получить строки в определённом порядке, то указываете `ORDER BY`, иначе порядок полученных записей не определён и может быть любым.

Для выборки конкретных строк используется ключ. Чтобы выбрать только две записи, используйте конструкцию `IN (1, 5)`.

В общем, ответ на ваш вопрос может быть близок к чему-то такому -- здесь выбираются 1 и 5 строка, в порядке определённом полем Key1:

```
SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Key1) AS [RowNumber]
FROM dbo.test
WHERE [RowNumber] IN (1, 5)
ORDER BY Key1
```

Comment: Это если есть кластерный индекс, а не всё в куче (бррр!) валяется. Тогда строки хранятся вообще абы как.

Comment: Автор вопроса принял ваш ответ, а потом всё же уточнил постановку задачи. Ему не нужны такие сложности с нумерацией строк, если не сложно: допишите пару строк в ответ.